# Vectorizing matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to transform the matrix product AX-XB into vector form.

That is `Cx` where `x=vec(X)`

Yet I found the last term `(XB)` is very difficult to vectorize, it would be very sparsy.

Any effective way to do this?

Please [see this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353329/solution-of-a-sylvester-equation) for the transformation to vector form

Comment: What is `vec`? What do you mean by this question? `A*X-X*B` is already vectorized?

Comment: vec is the vectorizing operation, just like flattening a matrix into vector. Details can be found in this wiki link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @Rein: Do you need to find `C`? Do you need to find `Cx` as vector? You know that `xVec = x(:)`, right?

Comment: Yes I need to find such a C

Comment: Guess it is related to the Kronecker product function "kron" but it seems to be memory expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `C` explicitly - like for iterative solvers - you can define an abstract linear operator that returns the vectorized product `C*x`. Not sure, if there is such a particular function in Matlab as SciPy's `LinearOperator`, but an anonymous function should do as well:

```
C_x = @(X) vec(A*X-X*B);
```

where `vec` 'vectorises' the matrix, e.g. via `X(:)` as @Jonas has pointed out.

EDIT: A closed form was suggested by @Eitan T below!!

See [Matlab Help](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) for how to use anonymous functions and function handles.

The formula for the explicit `C` is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353329/solution-of-a-sylvester-equation).

Comment: But what is `vec` here? Is it from the file exchange? Matlab has no such function `vec`

Comment: @Jan Actually, you can implement `vec(x)` as `reshape(x, [], 1)`, which is equivalent to `x(:)`, so: `C_x = @(X)reshape(A*X-X*B, [], 1)`